# Media Being Hosted In SVN For Web Application

Tags: svn, network-attached-storage, cdn, storage

I have a client who decided to use SVN to host the media files and pulled by a web application for viewing.  What are the consequences of this, and wouldn't a better option be to use a NAS or CDN?

Comment: You can certainly use svn for deployments, but actually serving content out of svn? That's ridiculous. That won't even scale to one user let alone thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly did they set up?  Did they checkout a copy of their svn tree on a webserver somewhere?  If so, that's a perfectly acceptable thing to do (if you secure it so .svn is not accessible to everyone!).

Or are they trying to host this directly from the svnserve binary?  That would be less then optimal, and probably won't last too long once it sees a lot of traffic.

Comment: Directly from the SVNServe.